# Animation Nodes - Translate a set of object instances separately through a journey with multiple legs

Tags: animation-nodes

I have three subdivided planes that I'm using as start/end points for each leg of the journey (1 - 2 - 3). I've programmed one object instance (the moving colored plane) to travel between journey legs:

[image: object-journey]

I want to *separately* move each plane instance through each stop on the journey.

My guess is I need to loop through instances, calculating each object's position as it travels between stops, and update its progress throughout using a loop "reassign" parameter.

Here's my logic for just the first object's journey. I feel it's just way too complex for such a seemingly simple thing, and that someone with a better brain for this kind of logic could help think of a much more elegant solution:

[image]

Here's my blender file:
[image]

Comment: i assume you don't want to provide your blend file....?

Comment: @Chris I've now attached the file.

Comment: thank you for your blend file. That saved a lot of time for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Mix Vector List` node here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First - i have a solution - but...it is JUST a solution - it is not the best, not the most elegant and for sure it could be better. But it works.

I put your time calculation in a loop and of course had to adapt it a bit.

new node tree looks like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

You should rethink your time calculation ;) i think there you could do better.